# How to return multiple values of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here I am able to return one value `return fruit === 'cherries'`, how can I return two values , such as I tried `return [fruit==='cherries', fruit==='bananas']` , How can I return two values.

```
var inventory = ['apples','bananas','cherries'];
function findCherries(fruit) { 
  return fruit === 'cherries'  ;
}
console.log(inventory.find(findCherries));
```

Comment: Use `filter` instead

Comment: [fruit==='cherries', fruit==='bananas'] will return [true,false] if fruit is cherries - what would you want?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a logical OR -> `||` and `Array.filter`

```js
var inventory = ['apples', 'bananas', 'cherries'];

function findCherries(fruit) {
  return fruit === 'cherries' || fruit === 'bananas';
}

console.log(inventory.filter(findCherries));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could fiter it with an array of the wanted items.

```js
function findFruits(fruits) {
    return fruit => fruits.includes(fruit);
}

var inventory = ['apples', 'bananas', 'cherries'];

console.log(inventory.filter(findFruits(['bananas', 'cherries'])));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your inventory is below and u know which one is fruit then

```
function findMyInventory(type) {
  var inventory = ['apples', 'bananas', 'cherries', 'beans', 'roots'];

  var list = [];
  if ( type == 'fruits') {
    list.push(inventory.slice(0,2) );
  }  else if ( type == 'vegetables' ) {
    list.push( inventory.slice(3,4) ) ; 
  }

  return list;
}
```

if your list as below

```
var inventory = [
  { type: 'fruit' , name : 'apples'},
  { type: 'fruit' , name : 'bananas'},
  { type: 'fruit' , name : 'cherries'},
  { type: 'vegetable' , name : 'beans'},
  { type: 'vegetable' , name : 'roots'}
];

function findMyInventory(type) {
  var myList = [];
  for ( var item of inventory) {
    if ( type == item.type) {
       myList.push( item);
    }
  }
  return myList;
}
```